# Accessing (Windows Server 2008 R2) Virtual Servers using Hyper-V Manager for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, windows-8

I’m having several Windows Servers 2008 R2 which I previously accessed using Hyper-V Manager from Windows 7. On upgrading to Windows 8 and enabling the feature Hyper-V, this is no longer possible. I get an error message stating:

> “This version of Hyper-V manager cannot be used to manage servers running Hyper-V in Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2.”

[image: Error message accessing virtual server from Windows 8 client using Hyper-V]

How do I solve this problem and access my virtual servers using Hyper-V manager for Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All server management tools that are part of the Remote Server Administration Toolkit (RSAT) for Windows Vista manage only Server 2008.  And all server management tools that come with Windows 7 (as RSAT) manage only servers running Server 2008 R2.  And all server management tools that are part of Windows 8 (in this case, built in -- not the RSAT) manage only Windows 8.

This is true for all server rolls, not just Hyper-V.  And you wouldn't be the first person to say that you wished for something different.

If you want something that manages different types of servers from the same console, and you want it to come from Microsoft, that's System Center Virtual Machine Manager.

Comment: Thanx Jake, I'll take a look at System Center Virtual Machine Manager.

Comment: SCVMM does not currently support Hyper-V in 2012 or on Windows 8.  Further, this is SOMEWHAT INCORRECT.  AD utilities still work across versions and Jake claims "This is true for all server rolls".  Further, the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) for Windows 8 are not (as of this past weekend) available.  Only the Release Preview of the tools was.

Comment: You're right SCVMM for Windows 8 isn't there yet.  And I forgot that AD is special in that way.

Comment: Now that they're officially released, the situation is a little more complicated regarding RSATW8 backwards compatibility, but luckily there is a good official resource that clarifies exactly what WS2008R2 features you can manage using W8's tools (older Hyper-Vs remain excluded): https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2202.remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-vista-windows-7-windows-8-windows-server-2008-windows-server-2008-r2-and-windows-server-2012-dsforum2wiki.aspx